# Go recursive binary search

Tags: algorithm, go, binary-search

I know that Go has a `sort` package that contains search functions, but this is for educational purposes. I've been trying to implement a binary search algorithm in Go but I haven't been able to get it to work.

Here is my code:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func BinarySearch(data []int, target int, low int, high int) (index int, found bool)  {
    mid := (high + low) / 2
    if low > high {
       index = -1
       found = false
    } else {
        if target < data[mid] {
            BinarySearch(data, target, low, mid - 1)
        } else if target > data[mid] {
            BinarySearch(data, target, mid + 1, high)
        } else if target == data[mid] {
           index = mid
           found = true
        } else {
           index = -1
           found = false
        }
   }
   return
}

func main() {
  data := []int {2, 4, 6, 8, 9, 11, 12, 24, 36, 37, 39, 41, 54, 55, 56,}
  index, found := BinarySearch(data, 8, 0, len(data) - 1)
  fmt.Println(index, found)
}
```

It always prints `0 false`. Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The logic of your binary search is sound. The only problem is that you've forgotten to assign the result of each recursive call to `index` and `found`.

Currently you have these recursive calls:

```
BinarySearch(data, target, low, mid - 1)
//...
BinarySearch(data, target, mid + 1, high)
```

You merely have to assign the results:

```
index, found = BinarySearch(data, target, low, mid - 1)
//...
index, found = BinarySearch(data, target, mid + 1, high)
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Logic for Binary Search

- Target is to search for an item in an array.
- Get the middle item of the array.
- If more than the desired value => First item till the end item.
- If less than the desired value => Middle item till the end item
- Repeat process

We implement this using recursion or a loop.

## Using recursion to make a binary search

Function will include an array where we will do a search. Then target value is equal to the  value we are searching for.
`lowIndex` will indicate the begining of our search.
`highIndex` indicates the last position of our search.
Then the function returns the position of the target value we are searching for.
The reason for including the `lowIndex` and `highIndex` in the arguments is to search a subset of the array.

```
func binarySearch(array []int, target int, lowIndex int, highIndex int) int {
    //specify condition to end the recursion
    if highIndex < lowIndex {
        return -1
    }
    // Define our middle index 
    mid := int((lowIndex + highIndex) / 2)
    if array[mid] > target {
        return binarySearch(array, target, lowIndex,mid)
    }else if array[mid] < target {
        return binarySearch(array, target,mid+1,highIndex)
    }else {
        return mid 
    }
}
```

## Using a loop to make a binary search

```
func iterbinarySearch(array []int, target int, lowIndex int, highIndex int) int {
    startIndex := lowIndex
    endIndex := highIndex

    var mid int

    for startIndex < endIndex {
        mid = int((lowIndex + highIndex) / 2)
        if array[mid] > target {
            return binarySearch(array, target, lowIndex, mid)
        } else if array[mid] < target {
            return binarySearch(array, target, mid+1, highIndex)
        } else {
            return mid
        }

    }
    return -1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://play.golang.org/p/BbL-y7pJMi

Works fine as far as I can tell.

Comment: @zola : He didn't formulate it well, but you can see in his code he made some fixes (the same as described in Michael Laszlo's answer) which make it works

Comment: @mordeus instead of effectively just a link-only answer, you should include the relevant information directly in your answer. In this specific case you should point out what you changed and why. (See the "Provide context for links" part of [answer]).